# Converting string to datetime with format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe that looks like this, but the current dtype is object. This dataframe is imported from a csv where there were no column heads and it didn't recognize the type when it imported.

```
time
2019-05-29 12:52:35  
2019-05-29 12:50:41   
2019-05-29 12:51:39  
2019-05-29 12:52:32 
2019-05-29 12:52:18
```

I've done datetime conversions before but I can't figure the format out. The documentation and other questions about this don't really help me, to the point I've been trial and erroring but no success.

this is the code i use now:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

which gives me this error:

```
ValueError: time data 0 doesn't match format specified
```

I've also tried:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
```

but then I get this error:

```
time data '2019-05-29 12:52:35' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I don't understand why I get different errors or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the code that defines the 5 dates and times you posted? Please, post a minimal and reproductibile code so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: You don't have `-` between your formatters. try `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. I also believe the `pd.to_datetime(...)` can guess the format

Comment: Try `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: have you tried infer_datetime_format=True? Also I see the error message does not have a space between %d and %H.

Comment: When i let it guess the format i get `day is out of range for month`

Comment: `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Two things you can try: 1: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], dayfirst=True)`. 2: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`

Comment: the ``error=coerce` worked. The other one still gave me the `day is out of range for month` error for some reason.

Comment: Can you post it as answer or should i remove this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you can try:

1. `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], dayfirst=True)`
2. `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`